# Proving the upper bound of edges in a convex polyhedron

Tags: discrete-mathematics, polyhedra, planar-graphs

The question is the following:

Suppose Every face of a convex polyhedron has at least $5$ vertices and every vertex has degree $3$.  Prove that if the number of vertices is $n$, then the number of edges is at most $5(n-2)/3$.

Assuming the convex polyhedron is in fact planar:
Let $n = v = \#\{\text{vertices}\}$, $e = \#\{\text{edges}\}$, $f = \#\{\text{faces}\}$.

$v \geq 5f$, so $v/5 \geq f$.

Plugging the above into Euler's formula...

> $v - e + f = 2$
>
> $v - e + v/5 \geq 2$
>
> $6v/5 - e \geq 2$
>
> $6v/5 - 2 \geq e$

I'm not sure where the fact that every vertex has degree $3$ would fit in, but this is for sure not the result the question was asking for.

BUT.

I'm leaning towards this solution, because the question never states that the graph is planar, and the numbers seem more plausible.  If the convex polyhedron is NOT planar, the only approach i can think of is the following, which I am also unaware how to finish.

The sum of the degrees $= 2  \#\{\text{Edges}\}$.
Since every vertex has a degree of $3$,
$3V = 2E$. Also noting that $V \geq 5$.

And I'm stuck here.

If anyone could point me in the right direction I would be greatly appreciative.
Thanks.

Comment: Why should $v \geq 5f$? Some vertices could be counted in more than one face. For example, if you have two pentagons sharing an edge lying in the plane, there will be $2$ faces and $8$ vertices, and $8 \not\geq 2\cdot 5$.

Comment: The fact that every vertex has degree $3$ means that exactly $3$ faces intersect at every vertex. So when you say $v\geq 5f$, you are counting each vertex $3$ times, one for each face.

Comment: @karakusc So it should be 3v >= 5f?

Comment: Yes, this inequality is correct, but do not know if it is useful.

Comment: @karakusc Yes. I'm pretty sure the correct approach here is to assume the graph is not planar. I've edited the bottom of my question to show where I am in my thinking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $F$ be the number of faces, $E$ be the number of edges, and $V$ be the number of vertices. Since each face has at least $5$ edges, and each edge is shared between $2$ faces,
$$
2E \geq 5F
$$
Using this upper bound on $F$ in Euler's characteristic for convex polyhedra
$$
F=2+E-V
$$
we get
$$
\frac{2E}{5} \geq 2+E-V
$$
which, if rearranged, gives
$$
E \leq \frac{5(V-2)}{3}
$$

Comment: Ah! Simple! I was too caught up in trying to find where the degree of vertices fit in, but the detail was actually irrelevant in the case of this proof. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution is correct, however, you can add the following:

- Every vertex has a degree of 3, so 3 edges belong to it.
- Every edge has 2 vertices.

Therefore:
$$2 E = 3 V$$
Using the formerly stated inequality:
$$ E \leq \frac{5 (\frac{2}{3}E -2) }{3}$$
$$ 9E \leq 10E - 30$$
The final solution would be:
$$E  \geq 30$$